My external SSD is dead, how can I recover it?
I haven't lost any important data or anything, but I spent 100 bucks on this SSD drive and it suddenly started giving I/O errors, which I presume means the SSD was pulled out from a critical state, I tend to lend my SSD a lot, so someone may have corrupted it unknowingly.
The disk is still visible to the BIOS, and I can detect it using gnome-disks, but whenever I try to format it, or inspect it with fdisk, it gives me errors, which to be fair, it's expected. I was wondering if I can recover this disk somehow instead of buying a new one right out the bat.

Use dd to wipe the start of the disk then start from scratch. It does sound like a hardware problem though.

@BobGoddard Please use the answer area for answers instead of the comment area.

@BobGoddard, sadly dd doesn't work either, it gives me the same output, I/O error, I'm not entirely convinced this could be a Hardware error, but at least I managed to back the data up with the testdisk utility.

first method: Go to Windows search bar, type cmd, and select Run as administrator, then type the chkdsk / f c: command and press Enter (replace “c” with your SSD drive letter).
second method: Download, install testdisk_win file to launch TestDisk on your PC.
In terminal home screen, select Create and press Enter. Find your SSD on the device list and select Proceed, then Select the Intel partition table to instruct TestDisk to scan and analyze your system partition (SSD). Press Enter to confirm, after that Select Analyze to analyze your SSD and search for lost partitions. Press Enter to confirm, TestDisk will display detected partitions. Select the one you wish to restore Enter, then Select Deeper Search to scan, analyze, and repair the selected SSD partition.

Windows does not mount the drive, therefore I cannot use chkdsk with drive letters, I also mentioned I already used the testdisk utility in the comments, it only helped to backup the data.
